# how to add custom class name to tick positioner in Highcharts using javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i know if i want to add class or id for any attribute in highcharts
i can do some like :

```
yxis:{
     className:"name"
}
```

but i want add class name to attribute in y axis
for example:

```
 yAxis: {
            tickPositioner: function(min,max){
                //here want to add class name
                className:"name",
                //end here
                var data = this.series[0].processedYData,
                    ticks = this.getLinearTickPositions(this.tickInterval, min,max);
                //add last point
                val = data[data.length-1]
                ticks.push(data[data.length-1]);
                ticks.sort(function(a,b){ 
                    return a - b;
                })
                return ticks;
            }
        },
```

Comment: So you want add a custom className for ticks?

Comment: it is not a regular ticks , it is listener to specific tick

Comment: It does not matter. In a positioner you define a tick's position, not the object itself. So you want to add a custom className for the ticks positioned via tickPositioner?

Comment: yes ,I want to add a custom className for the ticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a custom css class to tick you have to wrap tick's `render()` method.

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tick.prototype, 'render', function (p) {
  p.call(this);

  var axis = this.axis,
    mark = this.mark,
    tickClassName = axis.options.tickClassName;

  if (tickClassName && mark) {
    mark.addClass(tickClassName, true);
  }
});
```

Then set class name in options.

```
  tickClassName: 'my-tick',
  tickWidth: true, // it has to be set to non-negative value, otherwise ticks in y axis will not render
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/hpeq7Lbe/6/

Without wrapping, you can define a custom class for axis and then access to ticks via `.custom-class-name .highcharts-tick`.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/hpeq7Lbe/9/

Comment: in inspact chrome does not exist class my-tick after this solution.

Comment: Did you check the jsfiddle? I style the ticks via my-tick class with css - and they are styled.

Comment: yap i check it , one of them work but cannot do what wanted. i wrote specific tick because the tick is dynamic give me in y axis the current value. for styling i need class for that i ask how add class. i what to style the y axis dynamic value

Comment: Both of them work, and one of them allows you to add a custom class name for ticks. "yes ,I want to add a custom className for the ticks" so what was wanted?

Comment: in the end styling the dynamic  current value in y axis that the target but to do that i need class for the listener ticks, first is not working in my charts. second work but can not give option to style the y axis value

Comment: styling labels: https://jsfiddle.net/hpeq7Lbe/10/ if it is not working in your charts, then recreate the issue on jsfiddle

Comment: u can fill only the last one?

Comment: What do you mean? All yAxis labels are styled(red), aren't they?

Comment: i told you i do not want all , only specific one

Comment: So the question should be - how to add a class to a specific label on axis. You can do it via labels.formatter. For the last label there is a helpful property isLast. https://jsfiddle.net/hpeq7Lbe/12/